# Kotlin delegate properties implementing 'provideDelegate' operator function, but method never called

Tags: java, delegates, jvm, kotlin

I have a base type `DbType` which is open for extension for my models like this:

```
interface DbType {
    fun <T : Any> field() = PropertyMapper<T>()
}
```

The `PropertyMapper` class is implemented like this:

```
class PropertyMapper<out T : Any> internal constructor() {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") operator fun getValue(inst: DbType, prop: KProperty<*>): T {
        return ImplementationDetail.values?.get(prop.name) as T? ?: throw NullPointerException("No such ${prop.name} in type ${inst::class}")
    }

    operator fun provideDelegate(inst: DbType, prop: KProperty<*>): ReadOnlyProperty<DbType, T> {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

According to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#providing-a-delegate-since-11) entry in the kotlin documentation, I should be able to provide my own `ReadOnlyProperty<R, T>` by adding an operator function `provideDelegate` in the class that the property is delegated to. However, when I instantiate an object implementing/extending `DbType`, the operator function `provideDelegate` is never invoked. The "getValue" part works fine, but I want to intercept the property delegate creation at the time the object is created. Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly? Here is an example class:

```
class BasicUserInfo : DbType {
    val username by field<String>()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: It appears to be a bug in the kotlin plugin or gradle. If I build a clean project with `PropertyMapper` only having a single operator method called `getValue`, it works as expected: calling `PropertyMapper#getValue` on accessing the field.

Then, when I delete that method and instead use the `provideDelegate` operator method, it fails with a `NoSuchMethodError` (never calls the `PropertyMapper#provideDelegate` method). If I clean (manually deleting the build/out folders) and re-build with that setup, it runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not called? What I found wrong in your code is that when you implement the `provideDelegate` operator and that returns some delegate object other than its receiver, you don't need the `getValue` operator to be implemented, since it won't be used, it's the object that `provideDelegate` returns that will be used for the property access (see below).

Otherwise, your code is valid. I have slightly modified your example to make it more clear what happens:

```
class PropertyMapper<out T : Any> internal constructor() {
    operator fun getValue(inst: DbType, prop: KProperty<*>): T {
        println("PropertyMapper :: getValue") // note: never printed
        TODO()
    }

    operator fun provideDelegate(inst: DbType, prop: KProperty<*>): ReadOnlyProperty<DbType, T> {
        println("PropertyMapper :: provideDelegate")
        return object : ReadOnlyProperty<DbType, T> {
            override fun getValue(thisRef: DbType, property: KProperty<*>): T {
                println("anonymous ReadOnlyProperty :: getValue")
                TODO()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `DbType` and the `BasicUserInfo` were left unchanged.

Now, when I create an instance of `BasicUserInfo` and get its `username` (with the expression `BasicUserInfo().username`), I get the following output:

> ```
> PropertyMapper :: provideDelegate
> anonymous ReadOnlyProperty :: getValue
> Exception in thread "main" kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented.
> ...
> ```

And if I only create the instance, it's only the first line.

Please see [the runnable demo of this code](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/vevoajgh2snt4ov9cqmtfo0ejm/er9k5he550ur2qahn38707bu1a).

Comment: There's definitely something wrong either with the kotlin version I'm running or possibly the gradle plugin (not programming for android - just using the kotlin & java plugins).  When I remove the `getValue` method from the `PropertyMapper` class in your demo, it still works fine, as expected (i.e. only failing at the TODO() in the getValue method in the `ReadOnlyProperty` instance returned by the `PropertyMapper#provideDelegate`.  However, when I run it on my machine in my project it fails with a `NoSuchMethodError` when attempting to access the property

Comment: [Here's an example](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/i80l089pasrufarmko4a1juhju/smrs60ai2hva4c7hpffjbrvalq) (I modified yours) which more closely resembles what I'm trying to do and [here's the repository](https://github.com/prestongarno/ktq-codegen) and more specifically: the [interface](https://github.com/prestongarno/ktq-codegen/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/com/prestongarno/ktq/runtime/GraphType.kt) and [implementation](https://github.com/prestongarno/ktq-codegen/blob/master/compiler/src/test/java/com/prestongarno/transpiler/experimental/Query.kt)

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer - see my explanation below. If I can reproduce consistently in an isolated example I'll file a bug report